# Vector arithmetic

Tags: python, arrays, vector, vectorization

I am trying to create an array of evenly spaced elements ranging from  -n to n. (ex: -2, 2, up to 1000 evenly spaced elements). Then using the array to create 2 new arrays using 2 equations by doing vector arithmetic.

```
import numpy as np 
from math import sqrt 

width = 4 
intervals = 1000

xCoords = np.linspace(-width/2, width/2, intervals+1)
yList1 = sqrt(1 - ((abs(xCoords) - 1)**2))   
yList2 = -3 * sqrt(1 - sqrt((abs(xCoords)/2)))

print(yList1)
```

I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: `from math import sqrt` -- use numpy instead: `np.sqrt`

Answer (score 2):

Use numpy functions on numpy arrays instead of the `math` library functions. Try `np.sqrt` and `np.abs`